# No plot shows up from VS Code

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I initiated the VS Code window through a WSL Ubuntu terminal such as

```
/mnt/d/github/python/python_for_data_science$ code .
```

And test a plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 11)
y = x**2

# functional
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

By `Run Python File in Terminal`, it shows

```
/mnt/d/github/python/python_for_data_science$ /usr/bin/python /mnt/d/github/python/python_for_data_science/section_8_matplotlib.py
```

But I didn't see a plot. Have I missed something?

Comment: Have you tried waiting for your code to finish executing? Matplotlib may take some time to load on initial startup

Answer (score 3):

WSL might not have the ability to show UI. Alternatively you can run the code in the Python Interactive window in order to see the output. Try right-click and select `Run Current File in Python Interactive window`.